# Create hyperlink for image in a folder based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a sheet containing the employees data with a serial number in cell "B5:B500" and I have an ID image for each employee in a folder on my pc named with the same serial number of the employee in Column ("B") now I need to create an automatic hyperlink for the employee's ID image in column "V") based on the cell value in Column "B" whenever I add a new employee number *** here is the folder path ("D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs").

Now I have this function working perfectly but only for JPG file format and all what i need is to make it includes png,jpg & jpeg format

=HYPERLINK("D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs" & $B5 & ".jpg", $B5)

can you help please?

Comment: thanks for your answer but file name is changeable based on the cell value in cells (B5:B500) - How can i do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around the variation in extensions of your image files like this.
Lets say this is your worksheet structure:

[image: Worksheet example]

Lets say your image file names are the same as the IDs I have in Column A in the screenshot above (so 001.png, 002.jpg, and so on):

[image: image file names]

Then, if you put the code I posted for the custom function called imgPath() below into a Module like this:

[image: Creating a module]

[image: Function in module]

```
Function imgPath(path, imgNum As String)
    Dim imgNameWithExtension As String
    imgNameWithExtension = Dir(path & imgNum & ".*") 'Using multiple wildcards character (*) to get any extension.
    If imgNameWithExtension <> "" Then
        imgPath = path & imgNameWithExtension
    Else
        imgPath = CVErr(xlErrName) 'Dir() returns a zero-length string ("") if file wasn't found, in which case imgPath() returns an error.
    End If
End Function
```

And change the Hyperlink formulas in your worksheet to this format:

```
=HYPERLINK(imgPath("D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\", A2), A2)
```

[image: Worksheet formulas view]
[image: Worksheet view2]

You'll then get hyperlinks to the files that could be found, regardless of their extensions, but #errors for files that couldn't be found (to help troubleshoot). Clicking on valid hyperlinks opens up the associated files: in my case link 001 opens 001.png, and link 002 opens 002.jpg, but no files are opened in the cells with #errors.

Edit:
If you'd like to store values in the ID/Column A as numeric/general as opposed to text (as I have in my example); in other words, your Column A values will be 1, 2, 3... instead of '001, '002... Then you could use this modified format for the Hyperlink formula (while retaining the file naming convention of 001.png, 002.jpg...):

```
=HYPERLINK(imgPath("D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\", TEXT(A2,"000")), A2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the full filename as hyperlink. Currently, you are only providing the path, and as a consequence, when you click on it, it will show the folder.

I assume that your ID column just have an ID number or the like (without file exension), so the formula could look like

```
=HYPERLINK("D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\" & B5 & ".jpg", B5)
```

The second parameter is what is *displayed* in the cell, so maybe you have a better value (like the name of the employee) in another cell.

I would strongly advice not to put the path itself into the hyperlink. Instead, write the path somewhere in a cell. Can be on another sheet, you can give a name to it. Advantage is that if your image path changes or you pass the sheet to collegues and on their computer the path is different, you just need to change the value of that cell - the hyperlinks itself stay unchanged.

As example, I put the path name into Cell `Z1`. Then the formula looks simply like

```
=HYPERLINK($Z$1 & "\" & B5 & ".jpg", B5)
```

Or, giving the cell holding the path the name `ImagePath`

```
=HYPERLINK(ImagePath & "\" & B5 & ".jpg", B5)
```

Comment: even so, this will only work for jpg files - please read my question edit

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Change: Insert Hyperlink

- When a value is entered (deleted) in `B5:Blastrow`, the hyperlink is added to (removed from) the same row of column `V`.
- To update the existing rows, perform a 'Copy-Paste-Values' of column `B`.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const IMAGES_PATH As String = "D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\"
    Const IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".jpg"
    Const FIRST_ID_CELL As String = "B5"
    Const HYPERLINK_COLUMN As String = "V"
    Const FRIENDLY_NAME As String = "Image"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ws.UsedRange
        LastRow = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
    End With
    
    Dim rg As Range
    With ws.Range(FIRST_ID_CELL)
        If LastRow < .Row Then Exit Sub
        Set rg = .Resize(LastRow - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(rg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim icell As Range, hcell As Range
    
    For Each icell In irg.Cells
        Set hcell = icell.EntireRow.Columns(HYPERLINK_COLUMN)
        If Len(icell.Value) = 0 Then
            If Len(hcell.Value) > 0 Then hcell.Clear
        Else
            hcell.Hyperlinks.Add hcell, IMAGES_PATH & icell.Value _
                & IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSION, , , FRIENDLY_NAME
        End If
    Next icell
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
            
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

- After entering a name in column `C`, an ID is generated in column `B` via Excel formula. Then this code will use this ID as a basename of the corresponding image file, and using the *Dir* function, determine if such a file exists. If a file is found, it will create a hyperlink to it in column `V`. If not, it will clear the cell.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const IMAGES_PATH As String = "D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\"
    Const FIRST_NAME_CELL As String = "C5"
    Const ID_COLUMN As String = "B"
    Const HYPERLINK_COLUMN As String = "V"
    Const FRIENDLY_NAME As String = "Image"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ws.UsedRange
        LastRow = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
    End With
    
    Dim rg As Range
    With ws.Range(FIRST_NAME_CELL)
        If LastRow < .Row Then Exit Sub
        Set rg = .Resize(LastRow - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim nrg As Range: Set nrg = Intersect(rg, Target)
    If nrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim ncell As Range, icell As Range, hcell As Range
    Dim iFilePath As String, iFileName As String
    
    For Each ncell In nrg.Cells
        Set icell = ncell.EntireRow.Columns(ID_COLUMN)
        Set hcell = ncell.EntireRow.Columns(HYPERLINK_COLUMN)
        If Len(icell.Value) = 0 Then
            If Len(hcell.Value) > 0 Then hcell.Clear
        Else
            iFileName = Dir(IMAGES_PATH & icell.Value & ".*")
            If Len(iFileName) > 0 Then
                iFilePath = IMAGES_PATH & iFileName
                hcell.Hyperlinks.Add hcell, iFilePath, , , FRIENDLY_NAME
            Else
                hcell.Clear
            End If
        End If
    Next ncell
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
            
End Sub
```

Comment: Mr. VBAsic,  not all my images format is JPG buyt dirreferent formats Unfortunately the code is not working even for JPG  - i just changed the rage fron "B5" to (B5:B500) and from "V" to  ("V5:V500") but got nothing

Comment: I've edited the code a few times, so copy this version (refresh the page) and don't modify the constants the way you did i.e. use it as-is. Keep the ` .jpg` issue for another question, you're butchering this one.

Comment: Mr. VBasic - I did but no response even no error

Comment: You didn't share *"B5 contains the employee "SERIAL NUMBER" only automatically generated in the table..."* in your question and you didn't read *"When a value is entered (deleted)..."* at the beginning of my post. It can still be fixed relatively easily if you share the formula in column `B` i.e. another 'trigger' column is needed e.g. if you manually enter the names in column `A` and the serial is calculated in column `B`, then column `A` could be it.

Comment: sorry I though that all what be effecting is what B5 contains not how it's generated - yes it auto generated in the table with a funtion =IF($C5<>"",ROW()-ROW($B$4),"")

Comment: What's in `C5`? If another formula, then share it. I need the column where you enter data manually.

Comment: in C5 the employee name - enter manually